# Set directory path to files for installation on Mac

Tags: macos, installation, directory, osx-snow-leopard, dmg

I have some files which need to be placed in a specific directory on a mac system automatically by clicking on the dmg file.

How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. A dmg file is a disk image, it just contains files. You should create an [installer package](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/PackageMakerUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).